# OneNote pages API doesn't return pages in section-groups

Tags: api, rest, onenote

I'm using the OneNote REST API (documented [here](http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/get-pages)). According to the documentation, calling the 'pages' endpoint returns *"all the OneNote pages across all notebooks ..."*

The endpoint I'm calling: `https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/me/notes/pages`

This seems to work in most / some cases, but pages which are part of sections which are themselves placed in section groups aren't returned.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong on my side? Could it be a bug in the API or its documentation?

Comment: It does indeed sound like a bug. We'll get back to you. Do you happen to have a correlation ID from a response header? Not sure if we'll need it but they're usually helpful.

Comment: Want to keep you in the loop, even if I don't have a lot to tell you yet - early indications are that we have a repro of the problem. Sorry if progress seems slow as we're quite busy, but I promise we're investigating and I'm staying on top of it.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the updates. The correlation ID I have is: `X-CorrelationId: b33834d2-a549-4c9d-aff5-6ff8f4de29d3`

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, we had some issues finding the logs for that request. Do you mind providing these headers from another request? X-CorrelationId, X-OfficeCluster, Date. So sorry, thanks much.

Comment: Ran it again just a minute ago. Here are the fields you've requested: `X-OfficeCluster: weu-www.onenote.com`; `X-CorrelationId: 12c3f24b-b39d-48c5-8b77-9af70ce5c1a9`; `Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 07:38:21 GMT`

Comment: Got what we needed from this. We're investigating.

Comment: thanks. On a related subject - I'm constantly getting an internal server error (500) for a different OneNote API call. What's the right channel to provide you with the relevant details?

Comment: You can leave details here or e-mail me at dakeller@[[the_company_I_work_for]].com . As for your existing issue, we have an additional resource now working on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The OneNote API returns, by default, only 20 pages at a time. Using OData operators like $top and $skip, you can walk through all of the results of the API. We believe that the pages you're not seeing may be the result of not walking through all of the page results. The page result will also have a "next link" included to make this easier.