# Onenote does not return pages

Tags: onenote

This is similar question as [OneNote pages API doesn't return pages in section-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121451/onenote-pages-api-doesnt-return-pages-in-section-groups).

I'm using the Get sections and get Section pages with Sections expanded to get names for all pages in a notebook. However using the same requests all the time, the sections in section groups sometimes disappears, and wont reappear before recreating the group.

Is this a bug that one can somehow work around, or is there a better way of polling all the page names from a specific notebook? The pages need to be in order.

Comment: +1 seems that API doesn't works, but dev.onenote.com returns correctly result. Just count 0 and empty value

Comment: Hi Walliski, the OneNote API team received your e-mail and I've been assigned to help you with your issue. I'm digging into the logs of the request you sent us and I'll see if I can diagnose the bug.

Just for clarification, what do you mean by "the sections in section groups...won't reappear before **recreating** the group"?

Comment: With recreating I mean creating a new section group called "temp", then moving all sections into the new section group, and finally deleting the "broken" one.

Comment: Wow that's pretty serious! Thanks for that clarification. I will update here by the end of this week with preliminary results of the investigation. I will notify you when I post so that you don't need to keep checking :)

Comment: We couldn't reproduce the issue because we aren't sure of the life cycle of the Notebook (are people updating it, is sync affecting it, etc.)? The best way to reproduce the issue for us would be to provide us with a CorrelationId of a successful call, and a CorrelationId of an unsuccessful call. We will then compare the logs of each request to see what is different. The best situation would be that this Notebook is unmodified in between requests. If you could provide something like this, or more information about how the notebook is being used, that would be a huge boon for investigating.

Comment: The notebook is in use all the time. Do not think that it is breaking without anyone changing it, and it wont fix itself, one has to recreate the sectiongroup.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that is in use all the time. Unfortunately that makes it really hard to track down the bug. If you can create a dummy notebook and hook up whatever code you have to act on that notebook, and monitor it every now and then to see if a request fails, that would be great. If not, we understand (it is quite tedious), but there isn't much else we can do. I also replied to your comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get all the page names for a Notebook, a work-around exists by using an OData nested filter. The idea is to query for all pages, `$expand` the `parentNotebook`, and then `$filter` on the `id` of the `parentNotebook`. Here is an example URL.

`GET ~/pages?$expand=parentNotebook&$filter=parentNotebook/id%20eq%20'{$notebook_id_here}'`

Here is another SO question where someone employs a similar pattern: [Best way to use One Note API to GET specific pages in specific section in specific notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165859/best-way-to-use-one-note-api-to-get-specific-pages-in-specific-section-in-specif/36166118#36166118)

**Update:**

You can control the order of the returned pages by using OData's `$orderby` and specifying properties that exist on the entities in the returned entity set (in this case, the entity is pages). From [dev.onenote.com](http://dev.onenote.com): "The default [order] is `lastModifiedTime desc` (most recently modified page first)."

Under https://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/get-pages there is a section, "Page properties", that shows all the properties returned by this call. Since we are getting all the pages available to a user that exist in a notebook, the only property we can use is unfortunately `createdTime`.

The query param to add looks like `$orderby=createdTime`

In full:

`GET ~/pages?$expand=parentNotebook&$filter=parentNotebook/id%20eq%20'{$notebook_id_here}&$orderby=createdTime`

I just tested this using Fiddler against my own pages so I think it should work. The nice thing is that it is a single request.

GET `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?$expand=parentNotebook&$filter=parentNotebook/id%20eq%20'{$YOUR_NOTEBOOK_ID_HERE}'&$orderby=createdTime`

Comment: If I do this, will the pages have the "order" on them, so I know how they are ordered?

Comment: Should have probably specified it better. With "order" I meant the "pagelevel" parameter that is available from here: https://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/get-pages.

If that one is also available this could be an alternative. I'll have to look into it, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the `pagelevel` specifier isn't available for this endpoint :(. The workaround above is probably as close as we can get. If you can find a repro situation with a notebook that isn't live we can dig into it so that your original method will work 100% of the time.